# HTML/Grails- how to display a link as regular text

Tags: html, grails, hyperlink, gsp

I have to present a link argument as a regular string/text (so the user won't be able to click the link)

```
<span class="text-light">
    ${statusMessage?.toHtml()}
    ${statusMessage?.link}
</span>
```

`${statusMessage?.link}` is the argument link which present like(e.g)

```
<a href="/threebaysover/product/show/OQ%3D%3D" class="ui-link">2 tour</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
${statusMessage?.link?.replaceAll("<(.|\n)*?>", '')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​}
```

Comment: @user1690588- I got an error "wrong groovy code" in the editor:(

Comment: Application Error occured : startup failed:
Users_saritrotshild_threebo_develop_grails_app_views_news_mobile__statusMessages_gsp: 46: expecting &#39;}&#39;, found &#39;​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​&#39; @ line 46, column 184.
   ?.replaceAll(&quot;&lt;(.|\n)*?&gt;&quot;, &#39;&#39;)​​​​​​​​​​
                                 ^

1 error

Comment: Which editor you are using? 
I am using the code and it is working fine, no error.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA. I got also an error in the web itself. The page is not loaded

Comment: I guess there was a problem with the "copy-paste". Now it works!